# Please translate to Latin: “Power from truth”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like (if possible) a pithy version of the English phrase “Power from truth”.

“From truth, power” is another way of formulating the thought I am trying to convey.

Answer (score 3):

Related 1: [Potestas est in veritate. Quis vero, robustior](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/potestas-est-in-veritate-quis-vero-robustior)

Related 2: [A correct latin translation of "By the power of truth, I, a mortal, have conquered the universe"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/a-correct-latin-translation-of-by-the-power-of-truth-i-a-mortal-have-conquer)

Neither of these provide an exact translation of what you're looking for, but they save on having to explain the words chosen and why you have options.

Depending on what you want your phrase to connote, you can choose from these words of power:

> Potestas / auctoritas / vis

Add the preposition:

> ex

And top it off with either a word for truth:

> vero / veris / veritate

I think putting the *ex ver...* first (e.g. ***ex veritate potestas***) sounds better, and you have parallels like *e pluribus unum* to back that up.